# Mapbox GL JS Toggle Layers default to "off"

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl, mapbox-studio

Using Mapbox's ['Toggle Layer' example](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/toggle-layers/), how would I load the map with the "contours" and "museums" layers turned off?

I want the layers to be turned "off" by default and have the user turn "on" the layers.

I've tried replacing

```
link.className = 'active';
```

With

```
link.className = '';
```

Per [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/206441/mapbox-gl-js-default-state-of-toggle-layers), but still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Additionally to what you've done replacing

`link.className = 'active';` with `link.className = '';`,

you need to set

`'visibility': 'none'`

for both layers when adding them to the map:

Example:
http://jsbin.com/vosenopedu/edit?html,output

Comment: Fantastic, thanks so much for your help!  This worked perfectly!